# Getting the part of string in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the part of string which is just before the second forward slash. Ok for easy i lets say i have a string named hello and it is :

```
$hello="hey/mate/from/outside/nothing/is/to/be/done";
```

How to get part of string up to second slash so that it become

```
$x="hey/mate"
```

Yes i can get part of string up to first slash / by

```
$x=strtok($hello,  '/');
```

I tried to search the functions like that but could not find .

Is there any functions that i can use ? 
So can we get part of string up to second slash ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtok` keeps track of the string it breaks up, so you can use it as it describes in the docs

```
$str = "hey/mate/from/outside/nothing/is/to/be/done";

$first = strtok($str, "/");
$second = strtok("/");

echo "$first/$second"; // "hey/mate"
```

Answer (score 3):

explode the string by / and do what ever you want .try this

```
$hello="hey/mate/from/outside/nothing/is/to/be/done";
$a=explode('/',$hello);// returns an array 
echo $a[0]."/".$a[1];
```